# Writing a Loop over Structures in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a loop that will that every number in userIdx and then go into the structure magStruct and for each time through the loop take the matrix of indexes inside that structure and concatenate all the numbers into one matrix. Then I want to take out all duplicate copies of numbers so that I am left with a matrix of unique numbers of all the numbers from the index I want from the numbers I specify into the function.

magStruct is a structure and indexes is a matrix of doubles.

I have wrote the loop and the concatenation of the numbers but the loop gives me an error and even then I think every element of the a matrix will be matrices themselves rather than just the numbers. Also, what is the function that removes duplicate numbers in a matrix? Thanks.

```
function coverage = getCoverage( userIdx, magStruct)
% getCoverage returns the list of magazines for users in input vector
% Input Arguments:
% userIdx = an row vector with user indexes
% magStruct = the magazineData structure
% Output Arguments:
% coverage = a list of the unique magazines that users in userIdx subscribe to

a = 0;
for k = userIdx
    mags(a) = magStruct(k).indexes;
    a = a + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the size of indexes matrices in magStruct?

If they are numeric matrices with the same number of columns, you can concatenate them with

```
mag = cat(1,magStruct(userIdx).indexes);
```

For the same number of rows just change `1` to `2`.

To remove duplicated use [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) function:

```
magunq = unique(mag);
```

If indexes matrices have different size, it's a little more complicated. You can convert them to column vector first, then concatenate in the same way:

```
temp = arrayfun(@(x) x.a(:), magStuct, 'uniformoutput',0);
mag = cat(1,temp{userIdx})
```